# form_set_error on Drupal 6 using two identical forms

Tags: php, forms, drupal, drupal-6, form-api

I'm using Drupal 6 and i want to create a block, that shows a form which also can be found on a subpage.

To do that, i created a drupal form API Form form() with its validationhandler form_validate() and its submithandler form_submit(). Then, I added a form API form widget_form(), which is basically the same as form() - just minor style adjustments, with the validation/submithandler set to form_validate() and form_submit(), also I changed the action to go to the subpage where form() is displayed.

This works fine, but if there is an validationerror (when using the widget_form()), drupal marks the block-formular, not the one on the subpage.

This seems to work as designed, but isn't the required behaviour i want. So, any way to change that?
(I want the error shown on the form() - form, not the widget_form())

Thanks!

Edit: I tried to hide the block containing the widget_form()-Form on the page displaying the form() form, no error is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I think the approach used is not quite right. What you need to create is just one form and one set of validation and submit function. For the block use hook_block and create a block and inside the block view op you can call drupal_get_form and display the form inside the block and then theme the block using CSS or custom template files. Then from the block configuration page you can decide to not show the block at the URL (menu) where the full form is loaded. You have got that part right.